# Converting ppt to PDF from byte[]

Tags: c#, pdf, powerpoint, office-interop

Currently I am using Office Interop to convert a ppt (or) pptx file to PDF. If the file is on disk I know how to do the conversion, but when I have a byte[] in my hand how to do the conversion. Remember I don't want to save those bytes to the disk.

Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
N.Murali Krishna.

Answer (score 0):

For converting ppt to pdf from byte[],

http://freeslides.codeplex.com/

```
Presentation pres = new Presentation();
pres.LoadFromStream(yourStream);
pres.SaveToPdf("myPdf.pdf",FileFormat.PDF);
```